# save a bitmap image to external memory and store its loctaion in sqlite for later retrevial

Tags: android, sqlite, bitmap

i have a simple app that takes information from an API and stores it as an object and shown in listview, right now my object contains a url link to the image and i would like to know how i can store the bitmap image to the device and replace the url link with a link to the location of the file on the device, this is my current activity code:

```
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        // in the background:

        // get the address from the params:
        String address = params[0];

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        InputStream stream = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = null;

        // the bitmap will go here:
        Bitmap b = null;


        try {
            // build the URL:
            URL url = new URL(address);
            // open a connection:
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // check the connection response code:
            if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                // not good..
                return null;
            }

            // the input stream:
            stream = connection.getInputStream();

            // get the length:
            int length = connection.getContentLength();
            // tell the progress dialog the length:
            // this CAN (!!) be modified outside the UI thread !!!
            progressDialog.setMax(length);

            // a stream to hold the read bytes.
            // (like the StringBuilder we used before)
            outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            // a byte buffer for reading the stream in 1024 bytes chunks:
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int totalBytesRead = 0;
            int bytesRead = 0;

            // read the bytes from the stream
            while ((bytesRead = stream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                // notify the UI thread on the progress so far:
                publishProgress(totalBytesRead);
                Log.d("TAG", "progress: " + totalBytesRead + " / " + length);
            }

            // flush the output stream - write all the pending bytes in its
            // internal buffer.
            outputStream.flush();

            // get a byte array out of the outputStream
            // theses are the bitmap bytes
            imageBytes = outputStream.toByteArray();

            // use the BitmapFactory to convert it to a bitmap
            b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, length);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                // close connection:
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            if (outputStream != null) {
                try {
                    // close output stream:
                    outputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return b;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        // back on the UI thread

        // close the progress dialog
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.page_edit_image);

        if (result == null) {
            // no image loaded - display the default image
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            Toast.makeText(AddEditActivity.this, "error loading image",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            // set the image bitmap:
            imageView.setImageBitmap(result);

//this is where i would like to save the image to the device some how and put its location in the object instead of giving it a url for downloading it dynamicaly


        }
    };
}


    Movie movie = new Movie(subject, body, year, /* i would like this to be a link to a location on the device*/ urlPic);   

    Log.d("year check", movie.getYear()+"");
    Log.d("movie attributes", subject+", "+year+", "+rating+", "+watched);

    dbhandler.insertMovie(movie);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just Put this Code & Replace your Post Execute with this.**

> protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
>           // back on the UI thread
>
> ```
>     // close the progress dialog
>     progressDialog.dismiss();
>
>     ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.page_edit_image);
>
>     if (result == null) {
>         // no image loaded - display the default image
>         imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
>         Toast.makeText(AddEditActivity.this, "error loading image",
>                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>     } else {
>         // set the image bitmap:
>         imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
> ```
>
> //this is where i would like to save the image to the device some how
>   and put its location in the object instead of giving it a url for
>   downloading it dynamicaly
>
> **SaveImage(result);**
>
> ```
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> private void SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {
>
> ```
>   String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
>   File myDir = new File(root + "/demo_images");    
>   myDir.mkdirs();
>   Random generator = new Random();
>   int n = 10000;
>   n = generator.nextInt(n);
>   fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
>   file = new File (myDir, fname);
> ```
>
> //        Below code will give you full path in TextView
>
> **>         txtPath1.setText(file.getAbsolutePath());**
>
> ```
>   if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
>   try {
>          FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
>          finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
>          out.flush();
>          out.close();
>
>   } catch (Exception e) {
>          e.printStackTrace();
>   }
>       }
> ```

Comment: thank you for the help, sorry it was late at night and i had to get some sleep, i tried this code, when it tried this: FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

it catches the exeption, any ideas?

Comment: never mind! i had i premmision problem on my testing project and now it works!! thanks alot!!!!

Comment: Welcome Anytime. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this and change it around to your specifications

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
                 boolean success = false;
                 if (!folder.exists()) 
                 {
                     success = folder.mkdirs();
                 }

                 System.out.println(success+"folder");

                 File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/sample.png");

             if ( !file.exists() )
             {
                   try {
                    success = file.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
             }

             System.out.println(success+"file");



             FileOutputStream ostream = null;
                try
                {
                ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);


                result.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
                //bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
                   //ostream.flush();
                    //ostream.close();
                }catch (NullPointerException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Null error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "IO error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
```

and for the path you can use

```
file.getAbsolutePath()
```

witch will return a String that you can insert into your database

Comment: thank you! i tried this but i get the "FileNotFound" exeption, when i use the compress method on the bitmap ="result" am i missing somthing? all goes well until that portion.

Comment: im not exactly sure whats going on, can you post the stacktrace?